# How to name the element?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, terminology, definition

Let $G$ be a finite group. If we want to consider all elements that are noncentral elements, but the identity element is also included in the consideration, what is a suitable name for the list of elements?

Comment: $A = G \backslash Z(G) \cup \{e\}$ could be a possibility, what do you think?

Comment: You can just say "all noncentral elements and the identity", as you did. This is indeed a name. If you also need a formula, the look above.

Comment: Thank you so much